# OpenCL ambiguous context constructor

Tags: c++, opencl

I've just started learning OpenCL with the following tutorial:
http://simpleopencl.blogspot.hu/2013/06/tutorial-simple-start-with-opencl-and-c.html

I have a problem with the following code:

```
cl::Device defaultDevice = allDevices[0];
cl::Context context({defaultDevice});
```

The compiler says:
[image]

I think the compiler cannot choose between the 2nd and 3rd candidate, but I don't know how to force the compiler to choose the 2nd one.

I use Qt Creator on Windows 7 and AMD SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the braces. Just:

```
cl::Device defaultDevice = allDevices[0];
cl::Context context(defaultDevice);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you explain why I don't need the braces?

Comment: braces give you an initializer list (in this case used to initialize a `std::vector<cl::Device>`). the constructor you want to call only takes a single `cl::Device` in which case you don't need a vector of them so you shouldn't create one with the braces.